# Combining columns of different lengths into one data frame

Tags: r

I have the following three datasets:

CoverageData1:

```
Class    Coverage
Eval     0.6
Reader   0.96
Eval     0.2
Queue    0.33
Reader   0.5
Reader   0.28
Queue    0.66
```

CoverageData2:

```
Class    Coverage
Queue    0.61
Eval     0.02
Eval     0.9
Reader   0.48
Eval     0.99
```

I want to combine them in one dataframe like:

```
Class   Coverage1   Coverage2
Eval    0.6     0.02
Eval    0.2     0.9
Eval            0.99
Reader  0.96        0.48        
Reader  0.5
Reader  0.28
Queue   0.33        0.61
Queue   0.66
```

For this, I did the following:

```
new_data <- data.frame()
for(class in classes){
  c1 <- CoverageData1$Coverage[CoverageData1$Class == class]
  c2 <- CoverageData2$Coverage[CoverageData2$Class == class]
  new_data <- cbind(new_data,c1)
  new_data <- cbind(new_data,c2)
}
```

When I run this, I get nothing. I see that data in c1 and c2 but they are not combined in new_data. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: please use `dput` to avoid us having to manually type your data in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

`merge(CoverageData1, CoverageData2, by="Class", all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)`

see `?merge` for details

---

**EDIT:** You could actually just try `new_data <- cbind(c1,c2)` because you are now trying to `cbind` `NULL` value with some data.